# How to fix eslintrc The file does not match your project config?

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

In my typescript project, I am using eslint. The files below are in the root, and I have also subfolders `/dist` and `/src`.

eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
  },
  rules: {
    strict: 'error',
    semi: ['error', 'always'],
    'no-cond-assign': ['error', 'always'],
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking',
  ],
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "module": "ES2020",
    "target": "ES2020",
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "alwaysStrict": true
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

the word `module` on top has a red line with this error

```
Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided. eslint
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Your question was answered here
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61956555/why-is-typescript-eslint-parser-including-files-outside-of-those-configured-in>

Answer (score 107):

Update your `eslintrc.js` to include:

> ignorePatterns: ['.eslintrc.js']

Comment: After reading answers in the linked thread, this one seems like the most correct and "self contained" answer.

Comment: Better to add it to your tsconfig.json: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283139/1345639

Comment: This is also the solution to using cascading eslintrc files

Comment: heh, how ignoring the file from eslint can be marked as solution? it will just bypass it and will not lint, so your eslintrc.js may not look nice after some future updates

Answer (score 90):

## What is this error about?

The error is basically saying the file `eslintrc.js` **itself** is both:

1. Found by ESLint, but
2. Doesn't match the list of files it's supposed to lint

So, ESLint doesn't know what to do and freaks out!

Note that while this file doesn't include your code, you should decide whether you want this file to be linted (e.g. for tab vs space, or double quote vs single quote,) or not.

---

## What should be done?

You can omit either (1) or (2) from the conflicting situation above.

#### Solution 1: Tell ESLint to ignore the file

It's easier.  Just add the name of the file (e.g. `.eslintrc.js`) to `.eslintignore`.

You can also see [case 1.3 of my answer, here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56719951/2321594) for different ways it can be done.

- Pros: Quick. Easy. Painless.
- Cons: The formatting of this file *can* become inconsistent with other files in terms of tab/space or quotes style.

#### Solution 2: Tell ESLint to lint this file (Preferred)

Typescript-ESLint gets the list of files to include from `tsconfig.json` via `parserOptions > project`.

So, you can either add the file to the existing `tsconfig.json` (Solution 2.1) or create a secondary `tsconfig.eslint.json` to include files like this, that you want to be linted by typescript-eslint, but not necessarily processed by the Typescript compiler.

- Pros: This file, and other similar .js configs will also be included for lining and keeping everything consistent.
- Cons: You might not want these configs files to be linted.  Also, it takes a bit extra work anyway.

**Solution 2.1: add it to the existing tsconfig.json**

```json
// in tsconfig.json ...

    "include": [
        ".eslintrc.js",
        // ...
    ]
```

**Solution 2.2: add it to a separate `tsconfig.eslint.json` file**
Create a file names `tsconfig.eslint.json` with this content:

```json
// new file: tsconfig.eslint.json

{
    "include": [
        ".eslintrc.js"
    ]
}
```

and then inject it into `eslintrc.js`'s `parserOptions` > `project` (yes, `project` accepts both a string, and an array of strings) :

```json
// in eslintrc.js ...

  parserOptions: {
    project: [
        resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json'),
        resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.eslint.json'),
    ],
  }
```

PS. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61993196) is very similar, I shall give some credit to that.

Comment: Thanks, adding `.eslintrc.js` to the project explicitly solved the issue for me. I thought my glob patterns should have covered it, but apparently they didn't.

Comment: Fantastic explanation that makes things clear, thanks a lot!

Comment: This should be the preferred answer right now. Though, now it makes me wonder should I just ignore "File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES module.ts(80001)" or is there a way to specify that these config files should be CommonJS modules

Comment: I am voting for solution 2.2 as the only correct one.
Solution 2.1 has the following drawback, not mentioned above:
If you add it to "include" in tsconfig.json this file will also be used by typescript compiler, and you might start getting errors from typescript compiler.

not speaking about eslint.js in particular but any other file as well

Answer (score 9):

This is now documented in TypeScript ESLint's doc in [I get errors telling me "The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided"](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#fixing-the-error)

**TLDR: see "Additive option" below for the best solution in my opinion.**

Here's the relevant doc with added notes. This builds on a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686975/1030527).

> This error means that the file that's being linted is not included in any of the tsconfig files you provided us. A lot of the time this happens when users have test files or similar that are not included in their normal tsconfigs.
>
> Depending on what you want to achieve:
>
> - If you **do not** want to lint the file:
>
>   - Use [one of the options ESLint offers](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#ignoring-files-and-directories) to ignore files, like a .eslintignore file, or ignorePatterns config. **=> See [Solution 1 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686975/1030527)**
> - If you **do** want to lint the file:
>
>   - If you **do not** want to lint the file with type-aware linting:
>
>     - Use [ESLint's `overrides` configuration](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns) to configure the file to not be parsed with type information.
>
>       - A popular setup is to omit the above additions from top-level configuration and only apply them to TypeScript files via an override. **=> See the additive option below**
>       - Alternatively, you can add `parserOptions: { project: null }` to an override for the files you wish to exclude. Note that `{ project: undefined }` will not work. **=> See the subtractive option below**
>   - If you **do** want to lint the file with type-aware linting:
>
>     - Check the include option of each of the tsconfigs that you provide to `parserOptions.project` - you must ensure that all files match an `include` glob, or else our tooling will not be able to find it.  **=> See [Solution 2.1 of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686975/1030527)**
>     - If your file shouldn't be a part of one of your existing tsconfigs (for example, it is a script/tool local to the repo), then consider creating a new tsconfig (we advise calling it `tsconfig.eslint.json`) in your project root which lists this file in its include. For an example of this, you can check out the configuration we use in this repo:  **=> See [Solution 2.2 of this answer or examples below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686975/1030527)**
>
>       - [`tsconfig.eslint.json`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/tsconfig.eslint.json)
>       - [`.eslintrc.js`](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/.eslintrc.js)

### Additive option

With this solution, you only *add* (i.e. enable) the `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'` option (and other related options) for the TypeScript source files. Other files like `eslintrc.js` won't be affected by that configuration, but will still be linted according to the rest of the configuration.

Add this to `eslintrc.js`

```
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['src/**/*.ts'],
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
    parserOptions: {
      tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
      project: ['./tsconfig.json'],
    },
    rules: {},
  },
],
```

The above configuration only uses TypeScript ESLint for files in the `src` directory.

Note that all TypeScript ESLint rules also need to be in the `overrides` entry (i.e. not the root `rules` option) or you'll get error messages like this:

```
Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
```

### Subtractive option

With this solution, you *remove* the `parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser'` option for the `eslintrc.js` (or `eslint.cjs`) configuration file.

Add this to `eslintrc.js`

```
overrides: [
  {
    files: ['./.eslintrc.js'],
    parserOptions: { project: null },
    rules: {},
  },
],
```

The above configuration disables TypeScript ESLint for the `eslintrc.js` file. You can also add other files or folders in `override.files` to extend this behavior.

**Con:** all TypeScript ESLint rules also need be removed in the `overrides` entry or you'll get error messages like this:

```
Error: Error while loading rule '@typescript-eslint/dot-notation': You have used a rule which requires parserServices to be generated. You must therefore provide a value for the "parserOptions.project" property for @typescript-eslint/parser.
```

Answer (score 0):

If Jest would provide a way to configure a `.yaml` file it would avoid part of this issue. Cypress added their own `tsconfig.json` in their directory to cover for their test files but they have a similar problem with their config file.

If you want a minimalist `tsconfig.jest.json` it could look like this (no need to add other options):

```js
{
  "include": ["jest.config.js", "tests/*.ts"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68686975/5028085) answer, you can use below config in your `tsconfig.eslint.json` file

```json
{
  "include": [
    "./**/.eslintrc.js"
  ]
}
```

Above rule is more general and will ensure to also include `.eslintrc.js` file present in other folder of your project(Side note: You can add `.eslintrc.js` at any folder level inside your root project. This will allow you to override the behaviour of certain rules at that project level).

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question with a little different problem. I have a folder which contains some separate .ts files which I also want to run linter against (cypress folder). The option with creation of tsconfig.eslint.json really would work **but** including files twice is defiantly not an option for me. Imagine you have tsconfig.app.json/base.json/spec.json/cy.json and what, do maintain this include paths for all of them? No!

Especially I wonder why it is not an issue if you create a project via Nx. Or with just a newer versions of Angular (16+)

So for some reason we have to specify these ugly "files" + "parserOptions" fields in eslintrc.json. I even have to specify settings."import/parsers". and "import/resolver". I didn't find a proper way out.

But from this troubleshooting section I figured out we can specify as many tsconfigs as we want: [check it out](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/#i-get-errors-telling-me-eslint-was-configured-to-run--however-that-tsconfig-does-not--none-of-those-tsconfigs-include-this-file)

So I just added my desired `tsconfig` file from cypress directory and it started to work.

```
"parserOptions": {
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json", "./cypress/tsconfig.json"]
  },
```

Answer (score -2):

same error, this worked for me:
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4900#issuecomment-669743374
https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4900#issuecomment-707330674

looks like config file must be named .eslintrc and use json format instead of .eslintrc.js and parserOptions.createDefaultProgram must be setted to true

Comment: It's probably `createDefaultProgram` that 'fixed' it but that is a lot more memory intensive: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/967#issuecomment-539091676

Comment: Yes, please do not consider createDefaultProgram option anymore. It will significantly increase time of linting