# Error with my ".eslintrc.js" file - "Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser."

Tags: typescript, eslint

**ESLint seems to be unable to parse a ".eslintrc.js" file**.

Steps to reproduce:
I set up a new "hello world" TypeScript project as follows:

```sh
# Make a new directory for our new project
mkdir test
# Go into the new directory
cd test
# Create a "package.json" file
npm init --yes
# Install TypeScript
npm install typescript --save-dev
# Install ESLint (the linter)
npm install eslint --save-dev
# Install the Airbnb ESLint config (the most popular linting config in the world)
npm install eslint-config-airbnb-typescript --save-dev
# The import plugin for ESLint is needed for the Airbnb config to work properly with TypeScript
npm install eslint-plugin-import@^2.22.0 --save-dev
# The TypeScript plugin for ESLint is needed for the Airbnb config to work properly with TypeScript
npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^4.2.0 --save-dev
# Create the config file for TypeScript
touch tsconfig.json
# Create the config file for ESLint
touch .eslintrc.js
# Create the entry point for our TypeScript application
touch main.ts
```

I fill the "tsconfig.json" file with the following (a blank/default config):

```
{}
```

I fill the ".eslintrc.js" file with the following, as specified in [the Airbnb documentation](https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript#i-use-eslint-config-airbnb-base-no-react-support):

```
module.exports = {
  extends: ['airbnb-typescript/base'],
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
  },
};
```

I fill the "main.ts" with the following:

```
const foo = 'bar';
```

Then, when I run `npx eslint main.ts`, it correctly generates the following error:

```
  1:7  error  'foo' is assigned a value but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
```

Thus, ESLint appears to be working correctly. However, when I run `npx eslint .eslintrc.js`, I get the following error:

```
  0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided
```

This error also appears in VSCode whenever I open the ".eslintrc.js" file. The error needs to be solved so that ESLint can lint the rest of the file. (To clarify, I want the ".eslintrc.js" file to be linted in the same way that I want my TypeScript source code to be linted - e.g. have 2 space indentation and so forth.)

Additional info: I am on Windows 10 LTSC with Node v14.8.0 and npm version 6.14.7.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

When you're using typescript-powered eslint rules (when your eslint config includes a `"parserOptions.project"` config), eslint throws an error if you attempt to lint a file that isn't one of the files that's included in the typescript project.

This is due to performance reasons - it used to be that eslint allowed this, but doing so would cause a a large performance hit, so they [changed it to throw an error instead](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/pull/760).

The solution to linting files that aren't part of your TS project is to create a tsconfig that extends your "real" tsconfig, but includes all the files you want to lint.  This is usually called `tsconfig.eslint.json` and looks like this:

```json
// Special typescript project file, used by eslint only.
{
    "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
    "include": [
        // repeated from base config's "include" setting
        "src",
        "tests",

        // these are the eslint-only inclusions
        ".eslintrc.js",
    ]
}
```

And in your `.eslintrc.js` you'll change `project: './tsconfig.json'` to `project: './tsconfig.eslint.json'`.

This should resolve the error and allow the `.eslintrc.js` file to be linted.

Comment: Even after attempting to perform the steps above, I am still receiving the error.

Comment: why would we want to have that file linted by `typescript` if it is a `javascript` file?

Comment: @SalahAdDin It's not being 'linted by typescript', it's being linted by eslint with the `@eslint-typescript/parser`.  But since it's using the typescript compiler to provide typings, it needs files to be included in the typescript project being used.

Comment: Ok, but does not that parser parse the `javascript` file as `typescript` files?

Comment: @SalahAdDin Technically yes, but since the syntax of TS is a superset of the syntax of JS it doesn't matter.

Comment: But it gives a lot of errores related to typing, for example.

Comment: @SalahAdDin It's possible some of the TS-only rules you have enabled don't work well when run against JS files, and you may need the overrides section to only enable them for TS files.  But I usually don't run into this - the above configuration should work for most projects.

Comment: Which section is that?

Answer (score 3):

[Retsam‘s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64283139/8289918) works perfectly well. However, you could also only use @typescript-eslint/parser for TypeScript files by using [ESLint’s overrides](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/configuration-files#configuration-based-on-glob-patterns). This avoids having to create a new `tsconfig.json` just for ESLint.

```js
module.exports = {
  // Common configuration for .eslintrc.js and TypeScript files
  rules: {
    eqeqeq: "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    // ...
  },
  overrides: [{
    files: "**/*.ts"
    // TypeScript-only configuration
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    parserOptions: {
      project: "tsconfig.json",
      tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
      sourceType: "module",
    },
    plugins: ["@typescript-eslint"],
    rules: {
      "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error",
      // ...
    }
  ]},
}
```

Comment: Note that this approach only works with really simple ESLint configs. In my projects (and probably most projects), there are a lot of rules, and they are being inherited from a parent config like Airbnb or `eslint-plugin-typescript/recommended`. So it isn't feasible to split up N rules into "only JavaScript rules" and "only TypeScript" rules, because N is far too large.

Answer (score -1):

i have litle bit same issue and was fixed done.
It get error message with encountering suggests that ESLint's TypeScript parser is not considering the file api.ts located in packages/cdk/lib/construct/ as part of the project specified in tsconfig.eslint.json.
This can occur when the include pattern in tsconfig.eslint.json does not match the file's location.

To address this, ensure that the tsconfig.eslint.json(create if not existed) includes all the directories and files you intend to lint.

Try updating tsconfig.eslint.json as follows:

```
{
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "lambda/**/*.ts",
    "lib/**/**/*.ts", // Adjusted pattern to include subdirectories
    "*.ts",
    ".eslintrc.cjs"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

Below is sample eslintrc.cjs (my path is : packages\cdk.eslintrc.cjs)

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  globals: {
    __dirname: 'readonly',
  },
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
  ],
  ignorePatterns: ['cdk.out'],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.eslint.json',
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint'],
  rules: {
    '@typescript-eslint/no-namespace': 'off',
  },
};
```

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?