# Parsing error: Cannot read file '.../tsconfig.json'.eslint

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

The error `Parsing error: Cannot read file '.../tsconfig.json'.eslint` shows in all `.ts` files in the `src` folder including `index.ts`.

I have no idea how to set up configs. The issue just shows a red line and makes the file red. However, everything compiles and run fine. The entire Node project was created using the firebase CLI.

`tsconfig.json` file:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

`.eslintrc.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: "tsconfig.json",
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "@typescript-eslint/adjacent-overload-signatures": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-function": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-floating-promises": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-namespace": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-type-assertion": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/prefer-for-of": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/triple-slash-reference": "error",
    "@typescript-eslint/unified-signatures": "warn",
    "comma-dangle": "warn",
    "constructor-super": "error",
    eqeqeq: ["warn", "always"],
    "import/no-deprecated": "warn",
    "import/no-extraneous-dependencies": "error",
    "import/no-unassigned-import": "warn",
    "no-cond-assign": "error",
    "no-duplicate-case": "error",
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
    "no-empty": [
      "error",
      {
        allowEmptyCatch: true,
      },
    ],
    "no-invalid-this": "error",
    "no-new-wrappers": "error",
    "no-param-reassign": "error",
    "no-redeclare": "error",
    "no-sequences": "error",
    "no-shadow": [
      "error",
      {
        hoist: "all",
      },
    ],
    "no-throw-literal": "error",
    "no-unsafe-finally": "error",
    "no-unused-labels": "error",
    "no-var": "warn",
    "no-void": "error",
    "prefer-const": "warn",
  },
  settings: {
    jsdoc: {
      tagNamePreference: {
        returns: "return",
      },
    },
  },
};
```

I had tried restarting VScode, clearing the cache, and all to no avail. I am guessing I need to change some of the paths but I am not very good at changing the config files so I don't want to accidentally break the entire project.

Answer (score 471, accepted):

By default, the `project`s (in `parserOptions`) are resolved relative to the current working directory. If you run `eslint` in a different working directory to the folder containing `tsconfig.json`, @typescript-eslint/parser will not be able to locate the file.

To fix this, you can set [`tsconfigRootDir`](https://typescript-eslint.io/architecture/parser#tsconfigrootdir) to `__dirname`, which would make the parser resolve the project configuration relative to `.eslintrc.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  // ...
  parserOptions: {
    project: "tsconfig.json",
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  // ...
}
```

---

If you’re having some trouble with

```
/path/to/.eslintrc.js
  0:0  error  Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided
```

see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64271575/8289918).

Comment: It fixed all file warnings but the .eslint is still giving a new issue: Parsing error: "parserOptions.project" has been set for @typescript-eslint/parser.
The file does not match your project config: .eslintrc.js.
The file must be included in at least one of the projects provided

Comment: @dz1002 This is because @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin is trying to use the type-aware rules on the `.eslintrc.js` file, so it needs a TypeScript project for that. You could either disable those rules for the file or add a tsconfig for ESLint with `"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.js"]` and `"allowJs": true`.

Comment: @dz1002 https://stackoverflow.com/q/63879049/8289918

Comment: Thank you so much! I was confused as to why eslint was complaining about

Comment: Ok, fixed my problem.

Comment: The module.exports code is located in the submodule's `eslintrc.js` file for anyone wondering.

Comment: Is there a way to do this if you have an .eslintrc.yml file?

Comment: how would this work in .json?

Comment: should __dirname be replaced by the directory .tslint is in?

Comment: Helps me with WSL

Comment: For JSON, replace __dirname with "." for tsconfigRootDir

Answer (score 135):

A VSCode-specific approach, that worked for me was to create a `.vscode` folder in the root project directory and add the following property to the `settings.json` file inside it:

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

The `"src"` could be any directory, which should be in eslint's scope.

Comment: If you have the following directories in your root folder: "backend" and "frontend", this will work:

"eslint.workingDirectories": [
    "backend", "frontend"
  ]

Comment: For Firebase Cloud Functions, use `"eslint.workingDirectories": ["functions"]`

Comment: it worked for my firebase functions! thank you so much!

Comment: I had the similar issue and this worked for me perfectly!

Comment: this solved my issue for firebase functions

Answer (score 82):

For those using Angular and `eslintrc.json`, add the 2 stars to the project node like this:

```
"overrides": [
  {
    "files": ["*.ts"],
    "parserOptions": {
      "project": ["**/tsconfig.json"]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Can someone explain why the 2 astres needed?

Comment: first for name, second for type

Comment: fix my problem too. thanks

Answer (score 73):

Update your eslintrc.json file with the following line:

`"project": "PROJECT_NAME/tsconfig.json"`

with PROJECT_NAME being the name of your project (not a macro).

Comment: This is a simple and straightforward solution!!!

Comment: This worked for me using Ionic 6

Comment: I guess this would've worked for me if my project folder was at the root of my multi-project solution. But I needed to use "PATH_TO_PROJECT/tsconfig.json".

Comment: Do you have a link to docs? I'm getting _Error: ESLint configuration in ..\..\..\.eslintrc.json is invalid: - Unexpected top-level property "project"._" and couldn't find it (quickly?) in https://eslint.org/docs/latest/

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is if you happened to open the Workspace folder one level above the Project (as was in my case), just start a new Workspace with the ACTUAL project folder. That solved my Eslint error.

Comment: This worked for me as well, as I was using some test files that I was keeping stored in the projects parent directory after cloning a fresh repo. I imagine that setting some of these config options would work if we provided the project's parent directory in the config, but this way we don't have to dance around git commands. Cheers.

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by adding `@typescript-eslint/parser` to the extends:

[image]

Comment: Please post your code directly to the post, no need of adding extra extra URLs that can become invalid in the future.

Comment: Bro screenshotted it

Answer (score 8):

I suddenly started seeing this error using vscode. Restarting vscode has resolved my issue

Answer (score 3):

What fixed this for me is to simply navigate into the project directory containing my tsconfig.json, and that it was able to locate the file.

Otherwise, I liked @dheeraj9499's answer that you can modify your .eslintrc.json "project" array within "parserOptions" and locate where your tsconfig.json is located from within the current directory. So something like the following was able to find tsconfig.json in the correct directory:

```
"parserOptions": {
  "project": [
    "code/eMOS/Scripts/tsconfig.json",
    "code/eMOS/Scripts/tsconfig.spec.json"
  ],
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get the following error message in a **multi-module project in IntelliJ** (e.g. a folder containing several backend services as well as a frontend module), IntelliJ might not be able to tell what to do.

In my case I got the following error on top of a `.ts`-file:
[image]

To fix this, I have clicked on "ESLint settings..." and picked "Manual ESLint configuration"
[image]

Then I entered the path to the **frontend module root** folder in "Working directories:" and picked the correct path to eslint in "ESLint package" (which - in my case - was in `<frontend-module-root>/node_modules/eslint`).

This way I still get eslint to work and do not have to change any project-related configuration at all (it works from frontend module root folder in CLI already).

Answer (score 2):

**Parsing error: Cannot read file 'd:\test\testproject\tsconfig.app.eslint.json'.eslint**
One of the major issues I faced here because of the way the project folder is opened in vs code.

assume the folder structure is
**d:\test\testproject** where '**testproject**' is the angular project you are using.

if you are opening the test folder in vs code then navigating to testproject as below

```
D:\test>
D:\test>cd testproject
D:\test\testproject>
```

Doing this will create 2 settings.json files, one for the main opened folder and one for the child folder which in turn doesn't allow the settings to be applied properly.

So always opening the project folder directly in the vscode would help overcoming the issue, when all the dependencies are mentioned properly in eslintrc.json and tsconfig.json files would help in solving the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For those who have this problem with **ionic framework** do the Next:
open `.eslintrc.json` and verify

`“project”: [“tsconfig.json”, “the-parent-folder/tsconfig.json”],`

Change the parent folder with the folder that contains your project and say Good bye to that annoying error♥

Comment: This 1.) fixes the error in the source code, and 2.) allows eslint to run properly on your project. This should be the accepted answer. (I'm running Stencil.js, but I think the project type is probably irrelevant.)

Answer (score 2):

A VSCode specific approach that worked for me was adding the following to settings.json

```
"eslint.workingDirectories": [
    {
      "mode": "auto"
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error in Visual Studio Code when working on a typescript project via WSL 2 on Windows 10.

It was fixed by installing the [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) extension in VS Code.

The files were hosted in my \wsl$\Ubuntu\home<user>\ location. The error message specified the correct file location, and VS Code could open the file.

The above fixes using the root directory and parser options did not help.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me

```
"parserOptions": {
  "project": ["<YourProjectName>/tsconfig.json"],
}
```

Comment: For me, this removed the error in the source code, but running eslint then doesn't work.