# ESLint: Parsing error: Cannot read file tsconfig.json on WebStorm IDE on WSL2

Tags: typescript, npm, webstorm, eslint, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When cloning my repo and doing npm install on WSL2, I am getting this ESLint error on my IDE for all .ts files in my project:

> ESLint: Parsing error: Cannot read file `\\wsl$\ubuntu-20.04\home\project_directory\tsconfig.json`

This is showing up because of my `parserOptions` in my `.eslintrc.json` file.

My attempts at solving this issue:

- I followed this thread:
  [Parsing error: Cannot read file '.../tsconfig.json'.eslint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933543/parsing-error-cannot-read-file-tsconfig-json-eslint),
  by converting my json to a js file and using `__dirname`. However
  that does not fix the issue for me.
- I also tried going into my IDE and manually selecting `eslint` from
  my project's `node_modules`. Nothing seems to be removing this error
  for me.
- The weird thing is if I clone my repo on Windows (not WSL), and open the project on Windows, the project works fine and `eslint` shows no issues. Not sure why it's not working the same on WSL.

Any help would be appreciated as I am unsure what to do next.

`.eslintrc.json`

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended-requiring-type-checking",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2021,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "@typescript-eslint/restrict-template-expressions": ["error", {
            "allowNumber": true,
            "allowBoolean": true,
            "allowAny": true,
            "allowNullable": true
        }],
        "no-use-before-define": [2, { "functions": false }],
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "block-scoped-var": 2,
        "no-undef": 2,
        "no-loop-func": 1,
        "no-console": 1,
        "no-debugger": 2,
        "eqeqeq": 2,
        "strict": [2, "function"],
        "no-unused-vars": [2, { "args": "none" }],
        "no-prototype-builtins": "warn"
    }
}
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Visit https://aka.ms/tsconfig.json to read more about this file */
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "ES6",                                /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', 'ES2021', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "ESNext",                           /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    "sourceMap": true,                           /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    "outDir": "dist",                              /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    "strict": true,                                 /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "moduleResolution": "node",                  /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                        /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    "skipLibCheck": true,                           /* Skip type checking of declaration files. */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true        /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "backendbill",
  "version": "21.7.0",
  "description": "Running on AWS EC2 instance for api and bouncer",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "test": "npx jest --watch",
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\"",
    "prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\"",
    "deploy": "pm2 deploy ecosystem.config.cjs production",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "stage": "echo \"No tests just yet\"",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "preserve": "npm run build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"_/_.+(js|json)\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/..."
  },
  "author": "Brother Bill",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/..."
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/...",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^16.3.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.24",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.28.3",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.28.3",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.31.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.23.4",
    "eslint-plugin-node": "^11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^5.1.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^11.0.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "pm2": "^5.1.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2",
    "ts-jest": "^27.0.3"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,ts,cjs}": [
      "eslint --cache --fix",
      "prettier --check"
    ]
  }
}
```

Config Screenshots:

Automatic:
[image: Automatic]

Manual:
[image: Manual]

Comment: is the path to `tsconfig.json` shown in the error message correct? please share screenshots of **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Code Quality Tools | ESLint** and **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM** pages. Also, what do you mean saying that the issue goes away if you close your repo?

Comment: @lena Yes, 'project_directory' is under a different name but all else is fine. 

I shared screen shots above. One is set to automatic and the other to manual.

Comment: I apologize, 'close' was a typo and it's been corrected. What I meant was if I clone my repo on Windows and open the project directory in Windows, eslint shows no parsing errors.

Comment: Could you also share a screenshot of **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | Node.js and NPM** page?

Comment: @lena Thank you so much for mentioning that! I realized my Node interpreter was pointed at my Windows installation instead of WSL's. Changing it there fixes the issue for me.

Comment: Had the same issue. I worked under wsl2 on Windows10.
Found out my node was pointing at disk C.
When switched to ubuntu nodem this n=mistake wasa gone.