# Parsing error: Cannot read file '\tsconfig.json' eslint after following Firebase Cloud Functions initialization instructions

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, eslint

### Problem

Right after my TypeScript project initialization in VSCode using firebase tools for composing Firebase Cloud Functions following the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?hl=en) the very first line of the `index.ts` file displays an error:

`Parsing error: Cannot read file '\tsconfig.json'    eslint [1,1]`
[image]

and the `.eslintrc.js` displays an error:

`File is a CommonJS module; it may be converted to an ES6    module.ts(80001)`
[image]

**Since all files are auto-generated these errors are a complete surprise and I want to get rid of them.**

### Versions

For the record, here are the versions installed:

```
npm      --version 8.1.3
tsc      --version 4.4.4
node     --version 17.0.1
firebase --version 9.22.0
```

### Installation process

These are the commands I used in the powershell in VSCode with some info/warnings:

```
>npm install -g firebase-tools
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
...

>firebase init
...
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: undefined,
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v17.0.1', npm: '8.1.3' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
...

>npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
...
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
...

>firebase deploy
...
C:\Users\SAMS\firebase_dogout\functions\src\index.ts
  1:13  warning  'functions' is defined but never used  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
...
Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code2
```

### Files

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

#### .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
  },
};
```

#### index.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

export const helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs!", {structuredData: true});
  response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});
```

### What I tried

1. Reinitialization
2. Creating the `.vscode` folder with `settings.json` file with

```
 {
   "eslint.workingDirectories": [
       "src" // and "functions"
   ]
 }
```

3. Updating your eslintrc.json file with the following line: `"project":"PROJECT_NAME/tsconfig.json"`
4. Updating `.eslintrc.js` by setting `tsconfigRootDir: __dirname` in `parserOptions`
5. Deleting the ESLint extension. The error was gone, but `firebase deploy` command didn't allow the code deployement.

So, the [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933543/parsing-error-cannot-read-file-tsconfig-json-eslint) didn't really help

Comment: Where do you have the file hosted? Can you have this file in [Cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs) and read it from there instead of having it in function?

Comment: The `index.ts` file is hosted locally in `../functions/src`. Maybe I can load this file in Cloud Storage, but I want to load it to the Firebase Cloud Functions for the Cloud Functions functionality (I am not sure if I understood your suggestion).

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Ok, I have solved the problem with a great help of this github thread
[False positive Error - TS6133 error (declared but its value is never read) report](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19700).

I have changed `"noUnusedLocals"` setting in the `tsconfig.json` file from the default `true` to `false`, so the file becomes:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    ...
  }
```

However, the strange thing is that after successfully deploying functions to `Firebase Cloud Fuctions` using this setting and afterwards reverting the changes, the redeployment doesn´t show any error and is successful as well.

### Update

After retrying it a few time I must admit that the solution is different.
Turns out that the [related stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64933543/parsing-error-cannot-read-file-tsconfig-json-eslint) did help, in particular @cherryblossom solution. Setting `tsconfigRootDir: __dirname` in the `.eslintrc.js` file and restarting the VSCode solves the problem.

`.eslintrc.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  parserOptions: {
    ...
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
    ...
  },
  // ...
}
```

Comment: When I do this I get "Parsing error: Cannot read file '__dirname/tsconfig.json'.eslint" in my index.ts...

Comment: Try to restart the VSCode. Can't reccomend you anything else now.

Comment: @felixmp I got this error when I did this: "tsconfigRootDir": "__dirname", inside .eslintrc.json . I think you can't put __dirname as a string value. I didn't find a way to achieve this using a json file so I converted it to .eslintrc.js as Micheal has done.

Comment: in vscode you can ctrl + shift + p, Eslint: restarts eslint server

Answer (score 6):

I read the error message and studied it to death.
It was still popping up even after I had set up a basic project in firebase and tried to run it.
Finally in desperation I removed COMMENTED out a line from my

eslintrc.js

project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"], //REMOVE BY commenting
out

and so  my .eslintrc.js file was now reading
as

```
root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    // project: ["tsconfig.json", "tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: [
    "@typescript-eslint",
    "import",
  ],
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["error", "double"],
        "import/no-unresolved": 0,
      },
    };


And just to make sure I was not out to lunch 
I cleaned up the index.ts file as per recommedations and then I ran it...


PS C:\ac\x> firebase deploy --only "functions:helloWorld"
=== Deploying to '***********'...
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint
> lint
> eslint --ext .js,.ts .
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build
> build
> tsc
+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged C:\ac\x\functions (87.87 KB) for uploading
+  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: creating Node.js 16 function helloWorld(us-central1)...
+  functions[helloWorld(us-central1)] Successful create operation.
Function URL (helloWorld(us-central1)): https://us-central1-xxxxxxx-xx.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld
i  functions: cleaning up build files...
```

- Deploy complete!

I wasted a lot of time on this and I hope this is the end of it....

Comment: that worked out for me. It seems this is a going problem and the issue doesn't seem to be solved by contributors there on git-hub. I've seen twice this issue and they talk a little bit about it and then close to avoid more comments.

Answer (score 3):

i have the same error and added this line  `tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,` inside `parserOptions`  in the .eslintrc.js file as others suggested then the error went away.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

the following steps worked for me. I am not sure if they were all necessary but eventually I got to where I wanted to be. The steps previously mentioned here were not that helpful in my case probably because there can be many causes leading to the same error message. Finding a solution is sometimes a trial and error process until a solution is found.

In my case

1. I updated my nodejs at nodejs.org/en/download.

   nodejs.org/en/download

then I reloaded and reinitialized my Firebase functions project. And then I updated the typescript parser.

npm i @typescript-eslint/parser

and at last it seems to work. I will keep my fingers crossed that this is indeed the end of this painful two day process.